# Algorithm to count free blocks until there is a used block

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

It exists a 2 Dimensional Array for a field of (x,y) length, here for instance 9x6. What I need to do here is to check how many free fields are around the Orange and Red Star. The black (filled) fields represent the occupied fields. In this example for instance I have 7 free fields for Orange, 1 for Red. I know that I can loop through each field and see whether one field is occupied or not, but how could I loop through so that I know that these non-occupied fields are next to the Star or in the Radius of the Star of non-occupied fields? I hope I could elaborate my question well.

[image: Screenshot of Example]

```
Field[][] fields = new Field[9][6];

private void checkEmptyFields(Star star) {
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){ // Hardcoded size as an example
 for (int j = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   if(fields[i][j].isOccupied())
    { 
     //It is occupied, but what now?
    }
  }
 }
}
```

isOccupied Function:

```
public boolean isOccupied(){
return occupied;
}
```

I expect the output to be in this example Orange: 7, Red: 1 (because Red is blocked by the Orange Star and the occupied boxes)

Comment: Your question is how to find the number of free fields around a star, what is your definition of a free field? For example, does a free field have to be a certain distance from the star while not being occupied?

Comment: A free field are the fields, which are not filled black and which are not occupied by a star. Occupied means either a black filled bar is in the field or a Star is in this field. A free field can be anywhere.

If we for instance surround the Star by 8 occupied fields (since you need 8 black filled boxes to surround it), the star will have 0 free fields around it.

Imagine it like the places the star can kind of move around, so for instance 6 places it can move to and the rest is occupied If that makes sense?

Comment: and I'm also assuming you question is to find the free fields that are "reachable" from the star?

Comment: Yeah we could describe it as fields which are reachable from the star.

Comment: And if a field has a star, will `isOccupied` return true?

Comment: yes, it will return true when the box is filled or when a Star is placed on the field.

Comment: Seems you want to do a floodfill from both stars

Comment: According to google recursive flood fill with 4 directions looks how it should be kind of, although no idea how to do it yet @juvian

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python 2D fill algorithm", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a problem where breadth-first-search is the appropriate algorithm to use here. Breadth-first-search, or BFS, is when you visit all of a node's, or in this case fields', neighbors first. In your case, "visiting", will just mean checking if it's occupied or not. If it the neighboring field is not occupied and hasn't been visited before, then you can search that field and it's neighbors. The order in which you search is determined by using a Queue-like data structure like so,

```
private void checkEmptyFields(Star star) {
    boolean visited[9][6] = new visited[9][6];
    //get the star's coordinates somehow, you may have to change this
    int i = star.row;
    int j = star.col;
    visited[i][j] = true;

    int freeFieldCount = 0;
    Queue<Field> q = new LinkedList<Field>();
    q.add(fields[i][j]);

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
         Field current = q.poll();
         //get the coordinates from the field, you may have to change this
         i = current.row;
         j = current.col;
         int rowUpperLimit = i + 1;
         int rowLowerLimit = i - 1;
         int colUpperLimit = j + 1;
         int colLowerLimit = j - 1;
         if(rowUpperLimit >= 9) {
              rowUpperLimit = 8;
         }
         if(rowLowerLimit < 0) {
              rowLowerLimit = 0;
         }
         if(colUpperLimit >= 6) {
              colUpperLimit = 5;
         }
         if(colLowerLimit < 0) {
              colUpperLimit = 0;
         }
         //check immediate neighbors
         for(int m = rowLowerLimit; m <= rowUpperLimit; m++) {
             for(int n = colLowerLimit; n <= colUpperLimit; n++) {
                 if((m != i && n != j) && !visited[m][n] && !fields[m][n].isOccupied()) {
                     freeFieldCount++;
                     visited[m][n] = true;
                     q.add(fields[m][n]);
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    return freeFieldCount;
}
```

As user @juvian mentioned, this is an 8-neighbor approach. If you want to do a 4-neighbor approach, simply visit only the neighbors immediately to the left, right, above, or below the current field. You can modify the while loop like so,

```
while(!q.isEmpty()) {
         Field current = q.poll();
         //get the coordinates from the field, you may have to change this
         i = current.row;
         j = current.col;
         int rowUpperLimit = i + 1;
         int rowLowerLimit = i - 1;
         int colUpperLimit = j + 1;
         int colLowerLimit = j - 1;
         if(colLowerLimit > -1) {
             //check neighbor to the left
             if(!visited[i][colLowerLimit] && !fields[i][colLowerLimit].isOccupied()) {
                 freeFieldCount++;
                 visited[i][colLowerLimit] = true;
                 q.add(fields[i][colLowerLimit]);
             }
         }
         if(colUpperLimit < 6) {
             //check neighbor to the right
             if(!visited[i][colUpperLimit] && !fields[i][colUpperLimit].isOccupied()) {
                 freeFieldCount++;
                 visited[i][colUpperLimit] = true;
                 q.add(fields[i][colUpperLimit]);
             }
         }
         if(rowLowerLimit > -1) {
             //check neighbor below
             if(!visited[rowLowerLimit][j] && !fields[rowLowerLimit][j].isOccupied()) {
                 freeFieldCount++;
                 visited[rowLowerLimit][j] = true;
                 q.add(fields[rowLowerLimit][j]);
             }
         }
         if(rowUpperLimit < 9) {
             //check neighbor above
             if(!visited[rowUpperLimit][j] && !fields[rowUpperLimit][j].isOccupied()) {
                 freeFieldCount++;
                 visited[rowUpperLimit][j] = true;
                 q.add(fields[rowUpperLimit][j]);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid the messy ifs with max and min. Should also indicate that you are doing 8 neighbors approach

Comment: thanks, I'll give this one a shot and let you know whether this works.

Comment: I'll try to convert this to a 4 neighbour approach and let you know whether it works as intended. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @DaiSuki53 if you want to do a 4 neighbor approach, then visit the neighbors immediately to the left, right, above, and below the current field. I can modify my answer for that.

Comment: @ChrisGong Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Field>(); is supposed to be Queue<Field> q = new LinkedList<Field>(); right? Else I'm not understanding how you assign Integer to Field

Comment: The answer does work as it is intended! Thank you very much. Also highly appreciated @juvian for the approach.